# Cannot solve databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance issue

Tags: spring, spring-boot, rest

I have an issue with my post endpoint on my spring-boot server. I have model I want to send:

```
public class UpdateFiles {

    private final String name;
    private final ArrayList<File> fileList;

    public UpdateFiles(String name, ArrayList<File> fileList) {
        this.name = name;
        this.fileList = fileList;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public ArrayList<File> getFileList() {
        return fileList;
    }
}
```

Below there is a simple rest controller when i want return the same body as I received.

```
@RestController
public class RestClientController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/greeting", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public HttpEntity<String> greeting(@RequestHeader(name = "Content-Type", required = true) String contentType,
                                       @RequestHeader(name = "Accept", required = true) String accept,
                                       @RequestBody UpdateFiles updateFilesRQ) throws IOException {

        HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
        httpHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        httpHeaders.setAccept(Collections.singletonList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));

        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        String requestString = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(updateFilesRQ);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(
                requestString, httpHeaders, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

Here I have simple test to call post action.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {RestTemplateConfig.class, HttpClientConfig.class})
public class TestApplication {

    @Autowired
    RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Test
    public void getEmployees() throws IOException {
        final String uri = "http://localhost:8888/greeting";

        ArrayList<com.licencjat.filesynchronizer.client.model.File> listOfFiles = new ArrayList<>();
        listOfFiles.add(new com.licencjat.filesynchronizer.client.model.File("src/a", "01.01.01"));
        listOfFiles.add(new com.licencjat.filesynchronizer.client.model.File("src/b", "02.02.02"));
        UpdateFiles updateFiles = new UpdateFiles("yellow", listOfFiles);

        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

        HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
        httpHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        httpHeaders.setAccept(Collections.singletonList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
        String requestString = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(updateFiles);
        HttpEntity<String> request = new HttpEntity<>(requestString, httpHeaders);

        ResponseEntity<UpdateFiles> personResultAsJsonStr = restTemplate.postForEntity(uri, request, UpdateFiles.class);

        System.out.println(personResultAsJsonStr);
    }
}
```

After calling postForEntity I receive:

```
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageConversionException: Type definition error: [simple type, class com.licencjat.filesynchronizer.client.model.UpdateFiles]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of `com.licencjat.filesynchronizer.client.model.UpdateFiles` (no Creators, like default construct, exist): cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator)
 at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 2]

    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.readJavaType(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:246)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.read(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:228)
    at org.springframework.web.client.HttpMessageConverterExtractor.extractData(HttpMessageConverterExtractor.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate$ResponseEntityResponseExtractor.extractData(RestTemplate.java:998)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate$ResponseEntityResponseExtractor.extractData(RestTemplate.java:981)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:741)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:674)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.postForEntity(RestTemplate.java:449)
    at com.licencjat.filesynchronizer.client.TestApplication.getEmployees(TestApplication.java:53)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.java:74)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.java:84)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:251)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:230)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:58)
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of `com.licencjat.filesynchronizer.client.model.UpdateFiles` (no Creators, like default construct, exist): cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator)
 at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException.from(InvalidDefinitionException.java:67)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.reportBadDefinition(DeserializationContext.java:1589)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleMissingInstantiator(DeserializationContext.java:1055)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.deserializeFromObjectUsingNonDefault(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1297)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:326)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:159)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4202)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3258)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.readJavaType(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:240)
    ... 38 more
```

I know this might be simple question but I have been struggling with it for quite some time. I tried find my answer but none topics seemed related to my issue. I am doing something incorrect in the code? Do you know why I receive such an error?

Answer (score 0):

There can be multiple solutions to overcome this problem.

1. If your class is mutable: define a default constructor and create setter methods.

```
public class UpdateFiles {
    private final String name;
    private final ArrayList<File> fileList;

    // default constructor
    public UpdateFiles() {
    }

    // AllArgsConstructor, getters and setters
}
```

2. If your class is immutable: annotate the constructor with `@JsonCreator` and the fields with `@JsonProperty`:

```
public class UpdateFiles {

    private final String name;
    private final ArrayList<File> fileList;

    @JsonCreator
    public UpdateFiles(@JsonProperty('name') String name, @JsonProperty('fileList') ArrayList<File> fileList) {
        this.name = name;
        this.fileList = fileList;
    }

    ...
```

(A side note here: although there is no setters in `UpdateFiles` class, this does not means that is immutable. `fileList` is an `ArrayList` for which we have a getter, meaning that it is possible to be mutated from the outside.)